# Wrong alignment of split equation in align environment

Tags: amsmath

This is an example code of my problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
 \begin{align*}
    x_n&=\begin{split}
           &1+\frac{1}{2}+\left( \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4} \right)+\left( \frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}                {6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8} \right)+\cdots+\left( \frac{1}{2^{k-1}+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^k} \right)\\
           &+\cdots+\left( \frac{1}{2^{2N-1}+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{2N}} \right)
         \end{split}\\
       &>1+2^0\frac{1}{2^1}+2^1\frac{1}{2^2}+2^2\frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots+2^{k-1}\frac{1}{2^k}+\cdots+2^{2N-1}\frac{1}{2^{2N}}
 \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

It produces a giant blank gap between equality sign and split equations like the following:

[image]

I don't know what is wrong. Can anybody enlighten me?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want something like `\begin{aligned}[t]` or `\begin{multlined}[t]` instead of `\begin{split}`? By the way, you might need `mathtools` package.

Comment: Oh, `aligned` is an option, but is it really improper to use `split` in this case?

Comment: I always thought that `split` is only meant to be used inside an `equation` environment so it gets only one number the whole equation while you *split* it in many lines. And `aligned` for everything else.

Comment: @Manuel Well, thanks for that idea. But in `align` environment, each line of equation is also treated logically independent (thus one equation number per line). Shouldn't `split` also works in each line of these equations? On the other hand, according to `amsldoc`, "The split environment is a special subordinate form that is used only inside one of the others." Which I assume implicitly from the context, that "the others" include both `equation` and `align` and many others.

Comment: The amsmath package documentation also says 'The split structure should constitute the entire body of the enclosing structure,
apart from commands like `\label` that produce no visible material.'

Comment: @IanThompson Yes, I think I have understood. Thanks so much.

Comment: regardless of other considerations, the fact that you begin each line of the `split` portion with a `&` is what is pushing it to the right of what's on the longest line.  there's rarely a good reason to *begin* lines of a `split` (or most other multi-line) environment(s) with `&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be better off using the `multlined` environment from the [mathtools package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}  
x_n&= 
\begin{multlined}[t]  
 1+\frac{1}{2}+\left( \frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4} \right)    
  +\left( \frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{8} \right)
  +\cdots+\left( \frac{1}{2^{k-1}+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^k} \right)\\
  +\cdots+\left( \frac{1}{2^{2N-1}+1}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{2N}} \right)
\end{multlined}\\
&>1+2^0\frac{1}{2^1}+2^1\frac{1}{2^2}+2^2\frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots+2^{k-1}
\frac{1}{2^k}+\cdots+2^{2N-1}\frac{1}{2^{2N}} 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: equation]